# create checkboxes runtime and get values using DataBinding

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-binding-adapter

Currently i am using `DataBinding` in my application and it is working like charm. Now i have a question, can we create multiple checkboxes based on API response?

like i have one `ArrayList` in my model class, and whatever is the size of that arraylist that much checkboxes should be added.

```
{"hobby": [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "hobby": "Sports"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "hobby": "Hangout"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "hobby": "Skydiving"
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "hobby": "Scubadiving"
  },
  {
    "id": "5",
    "hobby": "Travelling"
  }
]}
```

Now i want to create checkboxes of all hobbies and want to retrieve values of selected checkboxes.

Can anyone help me with this?

i have created BindingAdapter for this, and able to create checkboxes runtime

```
@BindingAdapter({"bind:values"})
public static void createCheckboxes(LinearLayout layout, UserModel model) {
    List<UserModel.Hobby> list = model.getHobby();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        CheckBox chk = new CheckBox(layout.getContext());
        chk.setText(list.get(i).getHobby());
        layout.addView(chk);
    }
}
```

Now problem is how to get selected checkbox values.

#### Note :  need to implement it with DataBinding.

Comment: It depends on how you are showing data,
as if you are using listview or other like that then you need to add checkbox in your custom design view,
Or if you are showing it on screen directly then you need to customize your model class where your are storing id and hobby.

Comment: What is meaning of customize model class? can you please clerify it?

Comment: Never try this but you can check this [Blog](https://meedamian.com/post/two-way-data-binding/)

Comment: When you get data where you store it ???

For storing data you might have declare class like Hobby where you have set methods for getter and setter ID and Hobby that class.

Comment: @MD Thanks, nice hint, Two way binding might help me

Comment: @Vickyexpert thanks, i have already created all those things and implemented DataBinding so many times, but never done this kind of task, anyways thanks for help, will update question if i find any help or clue.

Comment: what have you implemented so far using `DataBinding`? whats your code?

Comment: @pskink you can check my updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally have done it, don't know whether it's correct use of databinding or not.

created binding method like this

```
@BindingAdapter({"bind:values"})
public static void createCheckboxes(LinearLayout layout, UserModel model) {
   List<UserModel.Hobby> list = model.getHobby();
   for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
      CheckBox chk = new CheckBox(layout.getContext());
      chk.setText(list.get(i).getHobby());

      final int finalI = i;
      chk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    UserModel.Hobby model=list.get(finalI);
                    if(model.isSelected())
                        model.setSelected(false);
                    else
                        model.setSelected(true);
                    list.set(finalI,model);
                    layout.invalidate();
                }
      });

      layout.addView(chk);
   }
}
```

and in my xml, created one `LinearLayout`

```
<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
     app:values="@{user}"/>
```

and while saving data, i am just checking with use of for loop and got which values are selected.

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    if(list.get(i).isSelected())
                    Log.e("", "selected: " + list.get(i).getHobby());
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

**How about this :**

```
LinearLayout root= (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.test);
// use loop 
CheckBox checkBoxOne = new CheckBox(this);
root.addView(checkBoxOne);
```

Comment: Great, how to do it with DataBinding?